# Autogrow on jEditable submits everything instead of doing a AJAX call

Tags: jquery, struts2, jeditable, autogrow

I'm currently working with jEditable plugin to compose an updatable text. My serverside is developed with Struts2 and the server urls that I invoke are struts actions that return JSON results. I use the following code to load the jeditable to my field (which is a H1):

```
 $("h1.myclass").editable("/MyApp/dinamic/updateText.action", {
    indicator : "<center><img src='/MyApp/images/loading.gif'></center>",
    submit    : 'Save',
    cancel    : 'Cancel',
    tooltip   : "Click to edit",
    onblur    : "ignore",
    name      : "myField",
    callback : function(value, settings) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(value));
    }
});
```

As you can see, in this code I'm not using the `type : autogrow` functionality yet, and it is working fine so far. The problem is that when I add `type : autogrow`, the corresponding text are is shown, but when I click the save button the browser is redirected to a url like

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/myform.action?myfield=YadaYada
```

where `YadaYada` is the actual text that I tried to save and `myform.action` is the page that I was already.

Does anyone have any clue why this bug is going on? \

**OBS**: I also tried using growfield2 instead of auto grow and the result is the same.

Comment: Have you figured tihs out? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not... The only fix I could manage to implement was disable Autogrow... =(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm not completely sure if I am right but I have been trying to solve this problem myself. What I've found is if some sort of your code is "slightly" off then it will cause the page to reroute. I've gotten the autogrow to work and I believe this should work for you:

```
        $.editable.addInputType('autogrow', {
            element: function (settings, original) {
                var textarea = $('<textarea />');
                if (settings.rows) {
                    textarea.attr('rows', settings.rows);
                } else {
                    textarea.height(settings.height);
                }
                if (settings.cols) {
                    textarea.attr('cols', settings.cols);
                } else {
                    textarea.width(settings.width);
                }
                $(this).append(textarea);
                return (textarea);
            },
            plugin: function (settings, original) {
                $('textarea', this).autogrow(settings.autogrow);
            }
        });

       $("h1.myclass").editable("/MyApp/dinamic/updateText.action", {
            type: "autogrow",
            indicator: "<center><img src='/MyApp/images/loading.gif'></center>",
            submit: 'Save',
            cancel: 'Cancel',
            tooltip: "Click to edit",
            onblur: "ignore",
            name: "myField",
            callback: function (value, settings) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(value));
            },
            autogrow: {
                lineHeight: 16,
                maxHeight: 512
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but except by adding the line with `type : "autogrow"` and the settings for autogrow's height I can't see what you've added. As far as I could notice your addInputType is standard right? You didn't ad anything.

Comment: Yes, the addInputType is standard. I think the more important part is that I put the autogrow: {} part as well as setting the type. When I left it off it behaved like you described. Did you try it with that?